# Using same variables in every function : how to make it more efficient than re-writing or copying every time

Tags: r, text, editor, coding-efficiency, pasting

So I have this :

```
colnames(df)<-c("long_name_1","long_name_2",...,"long_name_n")
```

and I want to use these names in this :

```
hist(df$long_name_1, main = paste("Histogram of'" , "long_name_1"),xlab="long_name_1")
hist(df$long_name_2, main = paste("Histogram of'" , "long_name_2"),xlab="long_name_2")
.
.
.
hist(df$long_name_n, main = paste("Histogram of'" , "long_name_n"),xlab="long_name_n")
```

Is there an easier way to do that than copying every name and pasting them three times each for their specific function ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to wrap the `hist` in a `for` loop:

```
long_names <- c("long_name_1","long_name_2",...,"long_name_n")

for(i in seq_along(long_names) {
  hist(df[, long_names[i]], main = paste("Histogram of'" , long_names[i]),xlab=long_names[i])
}
```

Of course you may want to wrap `hist` in a `pdf` as as well to output to pdf, but this saves your copying.